# How to test style for a React component attribute with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I am trying to test a style attribute for a React component. What is the best way to get style params in the test?

At this moment, my best option is to test if the HTML includes the string, but I think there is a better option.

Case:

```
it('Should render large image when desktop', () => {
    const dummyUrl = 'http://dummyUrl';
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <MockedStore
        initialState={{
          app: fromJS({ browser: { desktop: true } }),
        }}
      >
        <LandingHero bigImage={dummyUrl} />
      </MockedStore>
    );
  });
```

The Component to test is:

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import gc from 'styles/core.scss';
import $ from 'jquery';
import DownloadButton from 'components/DownloadButton';
import withStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/lib/withStyles';
import DownArrow from 'components/DownArrow';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import type { Map } from 'immutable';
import c from './styles.scss';

@withStyles([gc, c])
@connect(({ app }) => ({ app }))
class LandingHero extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if ($(window).height() > 0) { // Necesary for webpack dev server
      $(this.hero).css('height', $(window).height() - 46);
    }
  }

  hero: HTMLElement;

  props: {
    app: Map<string, any>,
    copy: string,
    secondaryText: string,
    thirdText: string,
    bigImage?: string,
    smallImage: string,
  }

  render() {
    const { copy, secondaryText, thirdText } = this.props;
    const browser = this.props.app.has('browser') ? this.props.app.get('browser') : {};
    const backgroundImage = browser.desktop ? this.props.bigImage : this.props.smallImage;

    return (
      <div
        className={`${c.hero} ${gc.textCenter}` +
        ` ${gc.alignMiddle} ${gc.alignCenter} ${gc.row} ${gc.expanded}`}
        ref={(hero) => { this.hero = hero; }}
        style={{
          margin: 0,
          position: 'relative',
          background: `linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba($ixdarkprimary, .3), rgba($ixdarkprimary, .3)), url(${backgroundImage || ''})`,
        }}
      >
        <div className={`${gc.row} ${gc.alignCenter} ${gc.alignMiddle} ${gc.column} ${gc.medium10}`}>
          <div className={`${gc.textCenter}`}>
            <div
              className={`${gc.white} ${c.mainText} ${c.copy}`}
            >
              { copy }
            </div>
            <div className={`${gc.small6} ${gc.smallOffset3} ${gc.medium4} ${gc.mediumOffset4}`} style={{ marginBottom: 45 }}>
              <DownloadButton />
            </div>
            <div className={`${gc.white} ${gc.fontBold} ${gc.font24}`}>{secondaryText}</div>
            <p className={`${gc.white} ${gc.font20}`}>{thirdText}</p>
          </div>
          <DownArrow goTo="#content" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LandingHero;
```

Comment: hey jacefarm what is the configuration you use for jest in order to use sass(scss)? I mean I have the following    ` "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(scss|css)$": "<rootDir>/src/sassMockForJest.js"
    },` but I got undefined errors when using properties for example if I used the same component like you I would see `Cannot read property 'textCenter' of undefined` because the `${gc.textCenter}`

Comment: Hey, you can get rid of your mock store by exporting your class as well. You get: `import ConnLandingHero, { LandingHero } from "../LandingHero";` It's saved our team a lot of time.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use [this](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/get.html) method. It returns ReactElement.

```
let containerStyle = container.get(0).style;
expect(containerStyle).to.have.property('opacity', '1');
```

Comment: For those using Jest, note that it should be `expect(...).toHaveProperty(...)` instead.

Comment: It should be `container.get(0).props.style`

Comment: Jest can get css style?

Comment: None of these are working for me. `wrapper.get(0).style` returns undefined as well as `wrapper.get(0).props.style`.

Comment: this will only work if style is a react prop like in the case of inline-styling

Comment: Same, none of the above worked but this ->  `wrapper.get(0).props.style` worked for me, when prop `style` is assigned to the component

Comment: try using `wrapper.props().style`, in my case I got rid of `get(0)` by directly using `props()` and it gave me the required `style` property

Comment: Unfortunately if you decide to change the way you do your styling in the future to use stylesheets, you will break all of your unit tests. That why you should not do it this way

Answer (score 35):

Slightly elaborating on others' answers:

```
expect(component.find('#item-id').prop('style')).toHaveProperty('backgroundSize', '100%');
```

This will check the `style` prop of `#item-id`. This prop is an object and here `toHaveProperty` matcher checks if this object contains `backgroundSize` property and if its value is `100%`.

This way other style properties are ignored.

Answer (score 32):

```
const elem = wrapper.find(Element);
expect(getComputedStyle(elem.getDOMNode()).getPropertyValue('opacity')).toBe('0.4');
```

Comment: this is the correct answer if you want to assert on external CSS style applied to the particular element — that's opposed to inline CSS styles passed as props etc.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much. This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: great!, i keep thinking this

Comment: The reason this should be the accepted answer, is because it is agnostic of implementation, using other answers, if you decide to move towards external style sheets, you will break all your unit tests, this way, you won't

Answer (score 21):

`expect(component.find('#item-id').prop('style')).to.deep.equal({display: 'none'})`

Comment: deep is very important here thanx

Answer (score 10):

If you use [jest-styled-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-styled-components#tohavestylerule) then you can use `toHaveStyleRule` as follows:

`expect(component.find('#item-id')).toHaveStyleRule('opacity', 'red');`

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at chaiEnzyme, which provides a handy little assertion you can use with chai to check whether a wrapper has a particular style (https://github.com/producthunt/chai-enzyme#stylekey-val), should help make your tests look a little cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it was a mash-up for a few answers.
For those also using **Jest / Enzyme**:

```
let containerStyle = wrapper.find('#item-id').get(0).props.style;

expect(containerStyle).toHaveProperty('opacity', '1'); // ('propert', 'value')
```

Note:

- find returns a `ShallowWrapper` so we need to `.get(0)` the first matching element
- `.props` is an attribute not a function in this instance
- jest uses `toHaveProperty` not `to.have.property`

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that the following `props()` method can also be used.
https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/props.html

`let containerStyleOpacity = container.get(0).props().style.opacity;
expect(containerStyleOpacity).to.be.equal('1');`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me also.

`expect(containerStyle.getDOMNode()).toHaveStyle('opacity : 0');`

I had to do this to replace

`expect(getComputedStyle(checkbox.getDOMNode()).getPropertyValue('opacity')).toBe('0');`

which worked when I ran the test locally in my Intellij IDE. However when I ran it using `npm t` it failed. Must be something to do with how `getComputedStyle` was being computed in the different scenarios.

`toHaveStyle` worked in both

Answer (score 1):

We do like this using ***import { shallow } from "enzyme";***

> const component = shallow();
>
> expect(component.find("[id="id_of_element"]")).toHaveStyleRule("border",
> "2px solid red");

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Enzyme has changed with recent versions but I needed parentheses after props in order to get the top answer to work.

`containerStyle = container.get(0).props().style;`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const node = wrapper.find(Element);
//Checking border property
expect(getComputedStyle(node.getDOMNode()).getPropertyValue('border')).toBe('2px solid red');
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: **identical** to [already existing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54788930/104380) older answer in this page