# How can I test React component's style with Jest + Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, jestjs, semantic-ui-react

Alright I have a component called `<TestButton />`. Inside the `<TestButton />` there are two Semantic UI React component, `<Button />` and `<Header>`.

Basically, when the `<Button>` is clicked, it toggles `display: none;` to `<Header>`.

I want to check (I want to learn) on how to assert `<Header>`'s `display: none;` when `<Button>` is clicked.

TestButton.js

```
const TestButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <div id='test-button'>
      <Header id='please-hide-me' size='huge'>Please Hide Me</Header>
      <Button
        onClick={
          () => {
            hiding = !hiding;
            let findDOM = document.getElementById(searchForThisID);
            if (findDOM) { findDOM.style.display = hiding ? 'none' : ''; }
            return hiding;
          }
        }
      >
        Sample Toggle
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

My unit test is based on [How to test style for a React component attribute with Enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795850/how-to-test-style-for-a-react-component-attribute-with-enzyme). It looks like this:

```
test(`

  `, () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TestButton />);
    const button = wrapper.find('Button');
    const header = wrapper.find('Header');
    const headerStyle = header.get(0).style;

    expect(headerStyle).to.have.property('display', '');
    wrapper.find('Button').simulate('click');
    expect(headerStyle).to.have.property('display', 'none');
  }
);
```

But it has this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your provided code:

1. You should not be using DOM element's style property because React does not manage it. Shift the `hidden` property into the `state` instead.
2. I believe `headerStyle` is a shallow copy of the style object. After you simulate click, it does not get updated. You will have to query the element again for the style object.
3. `to.have.property` is not valid Jest syntax. It should be [`toHaveProperty`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tohavepropertykeypath-value).

Please refer to the corrected code here. If you paste the following into [`create-react-app`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app), it should just work.

**app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

function Header(props) {
  return <h1 style={props.style}>Header</h1>;
}

function Button(props) {
  return <button onClick={props.onClick}>Click Me</button>;
}

export class TestButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hiding: false };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header
          id="please-hide-me"
          style={{
            display: this.state.hiding ? 'none' : '',
          }}
        >
          Please Hide Me
        </Header>
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({
              hiding: !this.state.hiding,
            });
          }}
        >
          Sample Toggle
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <TestButton />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**app.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

import { TestButton } from './App';

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<TestButton />);
  expect(wrapper.find('Header').get(0).props.style).toHaveProperty(
    'display',
    '',
  );
  wrapper.find('Button').simulate('click');
  expect(wrapper.find('Header').get(0).props.style).toHaveProperty(
    'display',
    'none',
  );
});
```

Comment: It solves my problem! Thanks. Is there anyway I can have the TestButton just as a `const` not a class? I learned that most ReactJS devs only use `const` as a component. Additionally: is using in-line style a good practice is ReactJS?

Comment: Nope, you need it as a class because you need to store `state`. Pure vanilla React inline styling is bad, but if you use stuff like CSS modules and jss, they do some post-processing to extract the inline styles out into stylesheets, which will be better.