# How to assert css property with chai

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

How to by using mocha/chai check if elements cssProperty to be x?

This is kind of what i want:

```
expect(accountText.getCssProperty('color')).to.be('#fff');
```

This is the error message i get:

```
expect(...).to.be is not a function
```

Comment: Try *equal*: `expect(accountText.getCssProperty('color')).to.equal('#fff');`

Comment: Seems like getCssProperty to look at the value of a  selector. This worked: expect(accountText.value.getCssProperty('color')).to.be('#fff');

Comment: Possibly related - [How to test style for a React component attribute with Enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40795850/104380)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
expect(accountText.getCssProperty('color').value).to.be.equal('#fff');
```

Comment: Hi Evgeny. Please can you explain why this solves the "is not a function" error to help the original poster.