# Is it possible to test that a css style property exists for a React component using enzyme + ava?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, ava

I'm looking to test that a component has an opacity value of 0 after firing an event, I have not found how to get/check for a specific css property with enzyme ([enzyme docs](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs)), is it even possible to do it just with enzyme & ava? Or is a third party library needed? At most I get the component props or the class name but I have no access to the style.

OBS: I don't want to use Jest instead of Ava, any other supporting library to work alongside with ava is welcome.
For the record, the answers in this question:
[How to test style for a React component attribute with Enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40795850/how-to-test-style-for-a-react-component-attribute-with-enzyme?rq=1)
Don't seem to work unless you use Jest.

Versions:

- ava: 3.8.2
- enzyme: 3.11.0
- OS: Catalina (macOs)
- node: v12.22.X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be done if it it not inline style (just with enzyme + ava), it's better to go for e2e tests for UI css checks.